# AS3 Collision Detection through hitTestPoint for a map based game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to work out the best way to perform a hitTestPoint for a game with a character, enemies and objects that are non-walkable in the map.

I have created a version that works, which can be seen here:
http://www.hosted101.net/hit/mapHitTest.html (arrow keys to move, you're the square).

Using a previously suggested method, I have created a secondary version of all objects on the map, increased by half the size of the player and am running a hitTestPoint from centerX and centerY of the player.

This is great and works fine.

However, I feel it is not optimal and it could be unnessesary to have all these extra "boundry boxes" created, even if the user can't see them.

So, I created a second version. This time without the boundry boxes:
http://www.hosted101.net/hit/mapHitTestNew.html (arrow keys to move).

As this is still running from centerX and centerY of the player, if you approach an object but are below centerX/Y, you will be able to travel through it.

My question is this: to hitTest objects vs players/enemies/anything on a game like this, what is the best method? (with a fixed example for this simple project would be great)

Is it really creating a duplication of the map layer with additional bounding boxes, or can it be done in a more clean way?

My code is below, for mapHitTestNew.

Thanks.

```
var moveL:Boolean = new Boolean
var moveR:Boolean = new Boolean
var moveU:Boolean = new Boolean
var moveD:Boolean = new Boolean
var moveSpeed:int = 2

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, updateKeysDown)
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, updateKeysUp)

function updateKeysDown(e:KeyboardEvent){
var _keyCode = e.keyCode
switch (_keyCode){
    case 37:
    moveL = true;
    break;

    case 38:
    moveU = true;
    break;

    case 39:
    moveR = true;
    break;

    case 40:
    moveD = true;
    break;
}
collisionCheck()
}

function updateKeysUp(e:KeyboardEvent){
var _keyCode = e.keyCode
switch (_keyCode){
    case 37:
    moveL = false;
    break;

    case 38:
    moveU = false;
    break;

    case 39:
    moveR = false;
    break;

    case 40:
    moveD = false;
    break;
}   
}

/**
***
*** Hit Test
***
***
**/

function collisionCheck():void{
var _MC:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
_MC.x = player.x
_MC.y = player.y
_MC.mouseEnabled = false

var centerX:Number = _MC.x + (player.width/2)
var centerY:Number = _MC.y + (player.height/2)

if(moveL){
    trace("Stage 1 Move")
    centerX -= moveSpeed
    if(map.hitTestPoint((centerX-player.width/2), centerY, true)){
        trace("Stage 1 HIT TEST!")
        moveL = false
    }
}
if(moveR){
    trace("Stage 2 Move")
    centerX += moveSpeed
    if(map.hitTestPoint((centerX+player.width/2), centerY, true)){
        trace("Stage 2 HIT TEST!")
        moveR = false
    }
}
if(moveU){
    trace("Stage 3 Move")
    centerY -= moveSpeed
    if(map.hitTestPoint(centerX, (centerY-player.height/2), true)){
        trace("Stage 3 HIT TEST!")
        moveU = false
    }
}
if(moveD){
    trace("Stage 4 Move")
    centerY += moveSpeed
    if(map.hitTestPoint(centerX, (centerY+player.height/2), true)){
        trace("Stage 4 HIT TEST!")
        moveD = false
    }
}
refreshMovement()
}

function refreshMovement():void{
if(moveL){
    player.x -= moveSpeed
}
if(moveR){
    player.x += moveSpeed
}
if(moveU){
    player.y -= moveSpeed
}
if(moveD){
    player.y += moveSpeed
}
}
```

Comment: check out the hitTest() method of the BitmapData class. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#hitTest%28%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're doing a kind of over-head view (considering you have the box moving in X and Y). I would have an 2D array with 0's and 1's in it (true/falses). When your character moves around, look up your characters hit box for the tiles that it occupies, which will generally be 1 to 4 tiles.

If there is a TRUE in any of thoses spots, he is hitting something. This way you only need hit boxes on objects that are active (they move etc)

I would also check out this article, and implement the solution that seems to work best for you:

http://higherorderfun.com/blog/2012/05/20/the-guide-to-implementing-2d-platformers/

Comment: thanks for the post - something that I wanted to do as much as possible was avoid using a tile based system as it removes a lot of the freedom of movement (unless you specify it to tiny tiles). Would you say that doing it with your suggested tile ("array") system is the superior way, compared to using boundry boxes around the map objects?